# Messages are not processed one after another

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I have an Inboundendpoint that connects to IBM MQ and reads messages periodically. I need to process messages one after the other. I need to wait until one message is fully consumed. But the messages are not always consumed sequentially. I have set the sequential flag to true. Here is a simplified version of my sequences.

```xml
<inboundEndpoint name="INBOUND_MQ_CONSUMER" onError="SEQ_MQ_ERROR" protocol="jms" sequence="SEQ_MQ_Process" suspend="false" xmlns=http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse>
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="interval">1000</parameter>
        <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="coordination">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">$SYSTEM:mq_in_queue</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.CacheLevel">3</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName">$SYSTEM:mq_in_connection_factory</parameter>
        <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial">com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url">$SYSTEM:PATH</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.UserName">$SYSTEM:MQ_USER</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.SessionAcknowledgement">AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.Password">$SYSTEM:MQ_PASS</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.SessionTransacted">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType">queue</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">application/xml</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.SharedSubscription">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ResetConnectionOnPollingSuspension">false</parameter>
    </parameters>
</inboundEndpoint>
```

```xml
<sequence name="SEQ_MQ_Process" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log level="full">
        <property name="Received Message" value="MQ1872"/>
    </log> 
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
            <inline xmlns=""/>
        </format>
        <args/>
    </payloadFactory>
    <call>
        <endpoint>
            <http method="post" uri-template="http://something">
                <suspendOnFailure>
                    <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                    <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                    <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                </suspendOnFailure>
                <markForSuspension>
                    <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                </markForSuspension>
            </http>
        </endpoint>
    </call>
    <log level="full">
        <property name="Processed Message" value="MQ1872"/>
    </log>
</sequence>
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a result of the non-blocking calls you are making. So simply Change your call mediators to blocking-mode.

```xml
<call blocking="true">
    <endpoint>
        <http method="post" uri-template="http://something">
            <suspendOnFailure>
                <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
            </suspendOnFailure>
            <markForSuspension>
                <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
            </markForSuspension>
        </http>
    </endpoint>
</call>
```